Confluence API only returning 500 unique records
I'm using the Confluence API to retrieve all pages across a number of different spaces. This was working correctly up until recently when I noticed the API has recently started returning only 500 unique records.
I know myspace has 1000+ pages but the results keep repeating the same pages. Is there some kind of limit being imposed?
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://confluence.internal.mycompany.com'
KEY = 'myspace'
TOKEN = "1234567890"
UNIQUE_PAGES = set()


def fetch_all_pages(space_key, start, limit):
    url = f'{BASE_URL}/rest/api/content'
    params = {
        'spaceKey': space_key,
        'limit': limit,
        'start': start
    }
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {TOKEN}'}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, verify=False)
    return response.json()


def get_all_pages(space_key):
    all_pages = []
    start = 0
    limit = 100
    while True:
        print(f"Start: {start}")
        data = fetch_all_pages(space_key, start, limit)  
        pages = data['results']

        if not pages:
            break
     
        for page in pages:
            page_id = page.get("id")
            if page_id not in UNIQUE_PAGES:
                UNIQUE_PAGES.add(page_id)
        
        print(f"Unique Pages: {len(UNIQUE_PAGES)}")

        start += limit
        if len(pages) < limit:
            break
    return all_pages

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pages = get_all_pages(KEY)
    print(f"Total pages retrieved: {len(UNIQUE_PAGES)}")


###OUTPUT###

Start: 0
Unique Pages: 100
Start: 100 
Unique Pages: 200
Start: 200 
Unique Pages: 300
Start: 300
Unique Pages: 400
Start: 400
Unique Pages: 500
Start: 500
Unique Pages: 500
Start: 600
Unique Pages: 500
Start: 700
Unique Pages: 500
Start: 800
Unique Pages: 500
Start: 900
Unique Pages: 500

